# Whats the difference between funding to mutisig address and general address start with '1'?

Tags: transactions, address, multi-signature, raw

I build raw transaction: '0100000001b0e1a9cc83fbe8918a1cf20e0c72cf2fe3af252f228a3a0223943c2732f69bd8010000006b483045022100cf98600ba4f4d7bc748e36e4bb7eed48a26d7eab45bb813f65781ca7921a163702204f857a25574ba50c54373dc9fcdbba51ac1653b1007832b8314a7ccc2224d927012102534fd869124dff1cc99c430b97a5b6817b1f8343ce1e1de3ff71d4a3fc6c1592ffffffff02307500000000000017a9146cf00a2686081c15e931f7413b0f07561388c9c18764000000000000001976a914e093b1e8185d6b8136a80c8ab02e2f0bbfaf15c288ac00000000'

but it failed to boardcast , are there some difference between funding to multisig address and normal address when building raw transaction and signing transaction?

You can also find both of two kinds of address appear in my outputs, does bitcoin network support this?

Comment: I tried to broadcast your transaction, but it's rejected due to dust outputs (you have a 100 sat output, which costs more in fees to spend than it's worth at the lowest fee levels).

Comment: thank you very much, I tried anthor transaction without dust outputs, successfully transfer.